# ReactJS Flask: One webpage link keeps using the wrong port 5000 on localhost instead of correct port 3000

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, port

I have a website with ReactJS frontend and Python-Flask backend with a link like so as the main page http://localhost:3000/. I have 4 pages, and 3 of the pages do the right thing to go to http://localhost:3000/page1, etc. However, one of the 4 pages (/sea in the example below), when I click on the link, always takes me to http://localhost:5000/sea, which is definitely not found. I can manually change the 5000 to a 3000 and the page works perfectly, but I am not sure what exactly is causing one of the four links I click to use port 5000 instead of 3000. All my code for going to the 3 websites is exactly the same. Here is the App.js file:

```
<div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                <Navigation/>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/villagers" component={Villagers}/>
                        <Route path="/songs" component={Songs}/>
                        <Route path="/sea" component={Sea}/>
                        <Route path="/seadetail" component={SeaMuseum}/>
                        <Route path="/" component={FrontPage}/>
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
```

As for the python Flask back end main.py"

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/villagers/')
@app.route('/songs/')
@app.route('/sea/')
@app.route('/seadetail/')
def index():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do `exact` unless you plan on using some route params.

```
<Route exact path='/sea' component={Sea} />
```

Could also be the fact that your package.json has "homepage" set to "http://localhost:5000" or "proxy" set to "http://localhost:5000" (You should remove these, if they have been set)

and you did `<a href="/sea">Hey go to sea</a>`

I would recommend you use

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

and <Link to='/sea'>Click to go to Sea</Link>
```

Also,I am assuming here you're using create-react-app. Your create-react-app's development server runs on port 3000. So if you're directing your user to localhost:5000/sea, your flask server will be the receiver of the request.

Also I am trying to understand your use case. So you're statically serving your create-react-app's public/index.html file? I think you should build your react app first and serve the build/index.html file

Something along these lines

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='project/build')

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def index(path):
    if path != '' and os.path.exists(app.static_folder + '/' + path):
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, path)
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=True, port=5000, threaded=True)
```